# Tricky Conditional Formatting Involving Actual Values vs. Displayed Values

Tags: excel, date, conditional-formatting, dayofweek

I have read other threads that are similar to what I need, but none of them are working due to my displayed date issues. Is is possible in Excel 2013 to set a conditional formatting rule to highlight cells in column C & D based on the displayed information in column B instead of actual data?

In Column B I have dates entered in as mm/dd/yy number format, but displayed as Day of the week, Month, Date, Year (example: 02/03/14 displays as Monday, January 3, 2014). I want to highlight the cells next to it based on the displayed text, not the numbers behind it.

My goal is to highlight the cells in column C-H if the dates in column B of the same row show either Saturday or Sunday. My first thought was to truncate the first three letters from each cell in column C into empty column A (showing as Thu Fri, etc) and reference that in my conditional formatting formula, but the LEFT function wants to grab the numbers and not the words from column B.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Weekday](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/weekday-HP005209336.aspx) function for conditional formatting:

```
=OR(Weekday($B1)=1,Weekday($B1)=7)
```

where 1 corresponds to Sunday and 7 to Saturday

Comment: After more research and reaching out to the community, I have my answer.
In A, I put =LEFT(TEXT(B12,"dddd"), 3). This displays the first three letters of the text date (instead of the number date). From there I do Conditional Formatting by highlighting the area I want highlighted, going to Conditional Formatting, New Rule, "Use a formula to determine which cells to format", and entering =$A12="Sat". Also make a New Rule for =$A12="Sun".

Now any date I put into column B will result in no highlighting for each week day, and highlighting for weekend dates.

Comment: @mid, why don't you want to use my solution? it's  simplier and there is no need to use additional column A